# How to set Working Directory global in Android Studio?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio

I am doing a unit test with my project which is of multi-modules. Every time I create a new Test and before running it, I have to do the something: Run -> Edit Configuration -> Set **"Working Directory"** to **"$MODULE_DIR$"**.If I don't do this, none of the resources can be found during the unit test. Are any global settings for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run -> Edit Configurations -> Defaults -> Android JUnit.

Config inside this page and it will perform globally.